# Web app to synch Facebook group events (and/or Google Calendar) to public RSS or similar

Tags: calendar, facebook, rss, plain-text, google-calendar

As initially asked on [Web applications](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/88368/synching-facebook-group-events-google-calendar-public-rss-or-similar) (but it was then suggested I try here), I'm looking for something that can take events from a Facebook group and make them visible to **everyone** (without requiring a Facebook/Google/Outlook.com account, iCal/.ics app, or anything). We already share them to a Google calendar, but even though it's public, you can't view it in Google Calendar without a login - and having to import it to something else like Outlook.com or a calendar app defeats the object, which is to make it as close to a plain text / HTML format as possible. We used to manage this via Yahoo Pipes / RSS but that's now defunct.

Our ideal is a website/web app that reads in from either the GCal or FB URLs and outputs a plain vanilla listing that everyone can view - in effect, automating "view [FB](https://www.facebook.com/groups/thanetclassics/events/), select everything in main frame, copy, visit website, paste as plain text, publish" would be great - but we don't have access to any server-side stuff. Most 'Yahoo Pipe replacements' we've seen look too complex: we only need one function. Suggestions?